# Recursive-descent parser

Tags: recursive-descent

The question is to write a recursive-descent parser for a language that contains sentences of form *w*+*w'*, in which *w* is an arbitrary string of lowercase chars,  *w'* is the **reverse** of w, and + the plus character. Examples of this language are:

- racecar+racecar
- example+elpmaxe

I can write a parsing function without recursion using a stack: just keep pushing until hitting '+', after which pop from the stack to check with the input character.

I don't know how to come up with recursive descent parser one. Textbook examples usually do not have such requirements for nonterminals.

Comment: Maybe this post helps: [Predictive and recursive-descent parsers](https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/wcbrown/courses/Su20SI413/lec/l10/lec.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try recursively popping off the front and the back, with a base case for checking if it’s a “+” when there’s only 3 characters left?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't actually need a recursive parser here as we can form our parser as

> **S->w+w'** *where + is in string itself and not have its actual meaning*

- Here we have only one Symbol.
- Recursion is needed when we have    multiple symbols and interrelated
  to each other.
  If you still want to make it recursive you can do it by

```
bool check(string S) {
    return recursive_check(S,0,S.size-1);
}

bool recursive_check(string S,int start,int end)
{
    if(end<0)
         return 0;
    if(S[start]=='+')
         return 1;
    if(S[start]==S[end])
         recursive_check(S,start+1,end-1);
    else
         return 0;
}
```